# django-ckeditor: uncaught exception using inlines

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ckeditor

I have two simple models **Question** and **Choice** (one question has multiple choices). I have used inline formset to add Choices along with adding Questions (through modelAdmin functionality).

```
class Question(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    question_text = RichTextField(max_length=2000, verbose_name="Question Text", blank=True)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    description = RichTextField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Choice Description")
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now the fields of Choice and Question are RichTextField defined in [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor). The issue is when I click on "Add another choice" I get an `uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.editor] The instance "id_choice_set-__prefix__-description" already exists`, which disrupts the ckeditor functionality.

Any ideas/suggestions how to fix this issue? I think some JS tweaks can help but I have a very limited knowledge in JS/Jquery

Thanks

Comment: I tried both admin and grappelli. Neither work. __prefix__ should get replaced with the number but isn't because django doesn't expect a __prefix__ to be in a javascript function. Here are some thoughts.


django/contrib/admin/media/js/inlines.js
See how __prefix__ is replaced, it doesn't replace it in the javascript. I wrote my own function something like 
el.html(el.html().replace(id_regex, replacement));
this replaces it correctly in the javascript code. BUT by then it executed incorrectly.


ckeditor/widgets.py contains the code that writes the javascript, not sure where to go from here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered similar issue and found a fix [here](https://github.com/20tab/django-ckeditor/commit/c23dcf815c3005493171529e6d0f2662a9fb21e2).

It's caused by **Inline** usage,try install the forked version to have try.

Though 6 months pass,hope this help those who got similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

[Line 66 of django-ckeditor's widgets.py](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor/widgets.py#L66) is where your problems seems to originate.

Essentially it seems, the substitution made for `final_attr['id']` is where you are getting the `__prefix__` from. Looking through the framework source code, [line 151 of Django's forms/formsets.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/forms/formsets.py#L151) is where that value comes from. Also, from the source, it seems that value will be replaced by the default prefix *i.e.* 'form' in all cases except if you are using `_get_empty_form()` incorrectly somehow.

It would be helpful if you provide/answer the following:

1. Once your page is rendered, but before you "Add another choice", post the tag attributes from your rendered formset (incl. the management form).
2. Are you using `_get_empty_form()` directly at any point in your code?
3. Code for the view where you create the formset and where you render it.